# If vector in image of linear operator, then it isn't in the kernel of the transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$ (for example let $V=\mathbb{R}^2$), $A \in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ be an $n\times n$ matrix, and $w\in V, w\neq 0$, such that there exists $v \in V$ with $Av=w$. Is it correct to say that always $A^Tw \neq 0$?

My attempt: I think it's always true that $A^Tw \neq 0$. We know that $v \neq 0$, and $v \notin \ker(A)$. We want to show that $A^TAv\neq 0$. $A^TA$ is symmetric. I can't seem to continue from here.

This isn't homework.

Edit: Thanks to @user8675309 comment, we can assume the characteristic of $\mathbb{F}=0$.

Comment: Take $A^Tw=A^TAv$ and multiply it by $v^T$ from the left. You get that $v^TA^Tw=v^TA^TAv=(Av)^T(Av)=\|Av\|^2$. If $A^Tw=0$, then $v^TA^Tw=v^T0=0$. But then $0=\|Av\|^2$. This implies that $w=Av=0$.

Comment: The claim is *false as currently stated*.  Let $A:=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1& 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\mathbf x:= A \mathbf e_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1  \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$.  I choose $\mathbb F:= \mathbb F_2$.   $A$ is symmetric and $A^T \mathbf x=A\mathbf x = \mathbf 0$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: After @user8675309 comment (beginning with "*This is still wrong*"), I've noticed that my attempt at proof was false, and therefore removed it.

Indeed, the statement in my question, as stated with $A^T$, is not necessarily true. Take $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$, and $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&i\\i&-1\end{bmatrix}$, and $v=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$, then $Av\neq 0$ and $Av \in Range(A)$, but $A^TAv=0$, therefore $Av\in \ker(A^T)$.

Comment: *This is still wrong*.  You've edited the original post to say " Thanks to @user8675309 comment, we can assume the characteristic of $\mathbb{F}=0$."  Fine.  I choose $\mathbb F:= \mathbb C$.  As I did before, I select any non-zero symmetric nilpotent matrix.  Contradiction.